# In what units the duration values are in this css code?

Tags: css

I tested if I change the duration value to 1 it will flopping each number every 1 millisecond and if i set it to 10 then each second.

in the duration the original value was 5s but it's not seconds.

here is a link with the css code and you can run it online: https://codepen.io/unframework/pen/LbaLvG

and this is the css full code just in case:

```
@digitWidth: 120px;
@digitHeight: 180px;
@halfHeight: @digitHeight * 0.5;
@duration: 10s;
@midPoint: 0.65; // used for timing z-index swaps; ease-in means that midpoint is later (slower at first)
@restAngle: 10deg;
@canvasBg: #e0e0e0;
@digitBg: #ccc;
@digitText: #444;

.defineDigitKeyframes(@prefix, @flipFraction) {
  @flipPct: 10 * @flipFraction;

  .keyframeIter(@i) when (@i < 10) {
    @kfParentName: ~'@{prefix}_flipParent@{i}';
    @kfTopName: ~'@{prefix}_flipTop@{i}';
    @kfBottomName: ~'@{prefix}_flipBottom@{i}';

    @startPct: mod(@i * 10 + 100 - @flipPct, 100);
    @midOnPct: mod(@i * 10 + 100 - @flipPct * (1 - @midPoint), 100);
    @fullOnPct: @i * 10;
    @fullOffPct: @i * 10 + 10 - @flipPct;
    @midOffPct: @i * 10 + 10 - @flipPct * (1 - @midPoint);
    @endPct: @i * 10 + 10;

    @keyframes @kfParentName {
      @startFrame: e('@{startPct}%');
      @{startFrame} {
        visibility: visible;
        animation-timing-function: step-end;
      }

      @midOnFrame: e('@{midOnPct}%');
      @{midOnFrame} {
        visibility: visible;
        z-index: 1;
        animation-timing-function: step-end;
      }

      @fullOnFrame: e('@{fullOnPct}%');
      @{fullOnFrame} {
        visibility: visible;
        animation-timing-function: step-end;
      }

      @fullOffFrame: e('@{fullOffPct}%');
      @{fullOffFrame} {
        visibility: visible;
        z-index: 1;
        animation-timing-function: step-end;
      }

      @midOffFrame: e('@{midOffPct}%');
      @{midOffFrame} {
        visibility: visible;
        z-index: 0;
        animation-timing-function: step-end;
      }

      @endFrame: e('@{endPct}%');    
      @{endFrame} {
        visibility: hidden;
        animation-timing-function: step-end;
      }
    }

    @keyframes @kfTopName {
      @midPct: @endPct - 0.001;

      @fullOffFrame: e('@{fullOffPct}%');    
      @{fullOffFrame} {
        transform: rotateX(0 - @restAngle);
      }

      @midFrame: e('@{midPct}%');    
      @{midFrame} {
        transform: rotateX(-180deg + @restAngle);
      }

      @endFrame: e('@{endPct}%');    
      @{endFrame} {
        transform: rotateX(0 - @restAngle);
      }
    }

    @keyframes @kfBottomName {
      @startFrame: e('@{startPct}%');    
      @{startFrame} {
        transform: translate3d(0px, @halfHeight, 0) rotateX(180deg - @restAngle);
      }

      @fullOnFrame: e('@{fullOnPct}%');    
      @{fullOnFrame} {
        transform: translate3d(0px, @halfHeight, 0) rotateX(@restAngle);
      }

      @endFrame: e('@{endPct}%');    
      @{endFrame} {
        transform: translate3d(0px, @halfHeight, 0) rotateX(@restAngle);
      }
    }

    .keyframeIter(@i + 1);
  }

  .keyframeIter(0);
}

.defineDigitKeyframes('left', 0.05);
.defineDigitKeyframes('right', 0.5);

body {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

b {
  @canvasWidth: @digitWidth * 5;
  @canvasHeight: @digitHeight * 1.5;
  
  display: block;
  margin-left: -@canvasWidth * 0.5;
  margin-top: -@canvasHeight * 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: @canvasWidth;
  height: @canvasHeight;
  background: @canvasBg;
  box-shadow: 2px -20px 100px -20px #888 inset;
  overflow: hidden;

  perspective: @digitHeight * 3;
  
  &::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: @canvasWidth * 0.9;
    height: @canvasHeight * 0.3;
    border-radius: 40%;
    
    background: transparent;

    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    z-index: 0;

    box-shadow: 0px -@canvasHeight * 0.95 40px -10px #fff;
    transform: translate3d(@canvasWidth * 0.05, @canvasHeight, 0);
  }
  
  &::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: @digitWidth * 2;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
    background: transparent;

    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    z-index: 0;

    box-shadow: 0px -25px 20px -3px #000;
    transform: translate3d(@canvasWidth * 0.5 - @digitWidth * 2 * 0.5, @canvasHeight, 0);
  }
  
  i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, serif;
    font-size: @digitHeight * 0.75;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;

    visibility: hidden;
    animation-timing-function: step-end;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    &.left {
      transform: translate3d(@canvasWidth * 0.5 + @digitWidth * (-0.55 - 0.5), (@canvasHeight - @digitHeight) * 0.5, 0);
    }
    
    &.right {
      transform: translate3d(@canvasWidth * 0.5 + @digitWidth * (0.55 - 0.5), (@canvasHeight - @digitHeight) * 0.5, 0);
    }
    
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    z-index: 0;
        
    &::before {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: @digitWidth;
      height: @digitHeight * 0.5;
      overflow: hidden;
      line-height: @digitHeight + 2px;
      background: @digitBg;
      text-align: center;
      color: @digitText;
      
      box-shadow: 0px 5px 60px -20px darken(@digitBg, 25%) inset, 0px -1px 3px -2px darken(@digitBg, 25%) inset;
      
      transform: rotateX(0 - @restAngle);
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      transform-origin: 50% 100%;      

      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      
      border-radius: 10% 10% 0 0;
    }
    
    &::after {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;

      width: @digitWidth;
      height: @digitHeight * 0.5;
      overflow: hidden;
      line-height: 2px;
      background: darken(@digitBg, 3%);
      text-align: center;
      color: darken(@digitText, 2%);

      box-shadow: 0px -5px 60px -20px darken(@digitBg, 25%) inset, 0px 2px 3px -2px darken(@digitBg, 25%) inset;

      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      transform-origin: 50% 0%;
      transform: translate3d(0px, @halfHeight, 0) rotateX(@restAngle);

      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          
      border-radius: 0 0 10% 10%;
    }
  }
  
  .iter(@i) when (@i < 10) {
    @leftChild: @i + 1;
    @rightChild: @i + 1 + 10;
    
    i:nth-child(@{leftChild}) {
      animation-name: ~'left_flipParent@{i}';
      animation-duration: @duration * 10;
      
      &::before {
        content: '@{i}';
        animation-name: ~'left_flipTop@{i}';
        animation-duration: @duration * 10;
      }
      
      &::after {
        content: '@{i}';
        animation-name: ~'left_flipBottom@{i}';
        animation-duration: @duration * 10;
      }
    }
    
    i:nth-child(@{rightChild}) {
      animation-name: ~'right_flipParent@{i}';
      animation-duration: @duration;
      
      &::before {
        content: '@{i}';
        animation-name: ~'right_flipTop@{i}';
        animation-duration: @duration;
      }
      
      &::after {
        content: '@{i}';
        animation-name: ~'right_flipBottom@{i}';
        animation-duration: @duration;
      }
    }
    
    .iter(@i + 1);
  }
  
  .iter(0);
}
```

I tried to play with the duration value but i still can't figure out what is 5s or 10s and in what units is it ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s` means second. The `duration` is for animating a whole cycle (0..9) of the last digit, that why when you set it to 10s, it flips every second.